# Trying to upgrade SQLite on Amazon EC2

Tags: php, sqlite, mediawiki

I need SQLite minimum version 3.8 to support a MediaWiki install on Amazon EC2. Amazon Linux is based on CentOS and the latest version available in the yum repository is SQLite 3.7.17.

The downloads available from sqlite.org don't include 64-bit Linux. There is a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/boramalper/sqlite3-x64) that has a prebuilt 64-bit version, however it's only the command line version. I put it at /usr/bin:

```
$ which sqlite3
/usr/bin/sqlite3
$ sqlite3 --version
sqlite3: /lib64/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by sqlite3)
3.26.0 2018-12-01 12:34:55 bf8c1b2b7a5960c282e543b9c293686dccff272512d08865f4600fb58238b4f9
```

But MediaWiki still complains I have SQLite 3.7.17 installed. When I test it I get:

```
$ cat x.php

<?php
print_r(SQLite3::version());
?>
```

Run it:

```
$ php7 x.php

Array
(
    [versionString] => 3.7.17
    [versionNumber] => 3007017
)
```

I am guessing this is because of these libraries:

```
$ sudo find / -name "libsqlite*"
/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0
/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
```

How can I download/rebuild or otherwise install a later version of these SQLite libraries?

Comment: More than 2 years on and Amazon Linux 2 still only supports SQLite 3.7! I rebuilt my instance on Ubuntu instead and things are much smoother.

Comment: @Jay seriously! but I couldn't even find source code for sqlite3 for > 3.8 versions for django.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest option I found was to build it myself. Tested on Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo).

1. Download the latest source code **with the configure script** from [here](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html). Currently this is:
   `curl https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-autoconf-3320300.tar.gz | tar xzf -`
2. Go into the created directory and create the Makefile with our system dependant options:
   `cd ./sqlite-autoconf-3320300 && ./configure`
3. Build the binary
   `make`
4. Install it
   `sudo make install`
5. Clean up
   `cd .. && rm -r ./sqlite-autoconf-3320300`

Note: It's far from ideal to do this without a proper RPM package. If you update sqlite through yum, you will overwrite you manually built version.

Comment: I followed the steps, but I'm getting the following after overwrite `/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0` and `/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6`"

```bash
[ec2-user@ip-172-20-234-20 /]$ sqlite3

SQLite header and source version mismatch

2021-06-18 18:36:39 
5c9a6c06871cb9fe42814af9c039eb6da5427a6ec28f187af7ebfb62eafa66e5

2013-05-20 00:56:22 118a3b35693b134d56ebd780123b7fd6f1497668
```

Comment: I fixed this by running:

`cp ./sqlite-autoconf-3360000/sqlite3 /usr/local/bin/sqlite3`

Comment: a more current version/link: curl https://www.sqlite.org/2022/sqlite-autoconf-3380500.tar.gz

Comment: Remembering to install gcc `yum install gcc` and if like me this is a production webserver, removing gcc afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

Adding on to @halbgut answer, with some changes:

1. Download the latest source code **with the configure script** from [here](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html). Currently this is:
   `curl https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-autoconf-3320300.tar.gz | tar xzf -`
2. Go into the created directory and create the Makefile with our system dependent options:
   `cd ./sqlite-autoconf-3320300 && ./configure`
3. Build the binary
   `make`
4. Install it
   `sudo make install`

Now, you have created the sqlite3 file. You need to replace them everywhere you find the file sqlite3.

To find all these places - run the following command:

```
whereis sqlite3
sqlite3: /usr/bin/sqlite3 /usr/local/bin/sqlite3 /usr/include/sqlite3.h /opt/c9/bin/sqlite3 /usr/share/man/man1/sqlite3.1.gz
```

Now within the sqlite source folder `./sqlite-autoconf-3320300`, find the `sqlite3`, `sqlite3.h` files and replace with the following cp command

```
sudo cp sqlite-autoconf-3320300/sqlite3 /usr/local/bin/sqlite3
sudo cp sqlite-autoconf-3320300/sqlite3 /usr/local/bin/sqlite3
sudo cp sqlite-autoconf-3320300/sqlite3 /opt/c9/bin/sqlite3 {I am using c9, hence this file, figure out what file is in the opt/ dir)
sudo cp sqlite-autoconf-3320300/sqlite3.h /usr/include/sqlite3.h
```

Once done, you would have upgraded both env and python-env. Now you need to just define the path to it. For it, use the local/lib in usr.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib"
```

Now you should have this :

```
$ python -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)"
3.23.3
$ sqlite3 --version
3.32.3
```

Comment: Life saver! Thanks a lot! was able to get the latest sqlite on amazon linux when building docker image as base

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the sqlite3 binary, the [SQLite amalgamation](https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html) also works perfectly on Amazon Linux 2. For SQLite 33.9.04 (or others from the [SQLite Download section](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)):

```
wget "https://www.sqlite.org/2022/sqlite-amalgamation-3390400.zip"
unzip "sqlite-amalgamation-3390400.zip"
cd "sqlite-amalgamation-3390400"
gcc shell.c sqlite3.c -lpthread -ldl -lm -o sqlite3
```

And then use it as you would any other software compiled from source:

```
ln -n ./sqlite3 ${wherever}/sqlite3
export PATH="${wherever}:$PATH"
```

[SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html) give a good explanation of further options if you need them.

Answer (score -1):

Get the latest sqlite3 download link from https://www.sqlite.org/download.html
and update the link given in the WGET bash command example shown below.

[image]

**Example:**

```
wget https://www.sqlite.org/2022/sqlite-tools-linux-x86-3400000.zip
unzip sqlite-tools*.zip
cd sqlite-tools* 
sudo cp sql* /usr/local/bin/  # Usually this directory is empty, so no need to worry about overwriting files 
cd ~
sudo yum update -y
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y 
sudo yum install glibc.i686 -y
# Fix your PATH variable to pick your latest binary files
# Also make sure to execute this command `hash -d sqlite3`
# if required.
hash -d sqlite3   # OPTIONAL STEP
hash -p /usr/local/bin/sqlite3 sqlite3 # OPTIONAL STEP
sqlite3 --version
```